# Is there an eloquent way to show that some content was automatically generated

Tags: symbols

When reading a blog read I saw a section at the bottom with this title:

> Related Posts (Automatically Generated)

I've also seen files with a header with something similar to denote that the content of the file was generated and it shouldn't be edited directly.

Is there a way to show this note more eloquently or maybe a universal symbol for generated content?

Comment: Does that **(Automatically Generated)** mean that the system is automatically picking related posts to display?

Answer (score 1):

**The most eloquent and efficient way to say it, is not to say it all**

What exactly is the point of communicating this information? I suggest you're overcomplicating matters, and certainly don't think using a novel icon is going to add value to the experience.

A great deal of the content we see online is automatically, or algorithmically curated. If it was really necessary to communicate this fact, we'd have seen language and icons emerge as a solution for doing it, but we don't have these.

The time to communicate anything along these lines is **when the content is personalized to an individual**. In that case, it's appropriate to say something like "Based on your reading history".

Otherwise, I recommend not communicating the point at all.

Comment: Agreed. Does anyone actually think those related posts are hand-curated?

Answer (score 0):

May be an icon of a bot face towards the top right corner of the post or at the bottom of the page.

[image: something like this?]

Answer (score 0):

I would use the magic wand symbol to denote:

---

*Generated Magically*

[image: magic wand]